# build vim with MinGW

Tags: vim, mingw, build-process

I'm trying to build vim with MinGW by running `./configure && make` in the vim repository root, but I'm getting the following error:

```
checking --with-tlib argument... empty: automatic terminal library selection
checking for tgetent in -ltinfo... no
checking for tgetent in -lncurses... no
checking for tgetent in -ltermlib... no
checking for tgetent in -ltermcap... no
checking for tgetent in -lcurses... no
no terminal library found
checking for tgetent()... configure: error: NOT FOUND!
      You need to install a terminal library; for example ncurses.
      Or specify the name of the library with --with-tlib.
C:\pdev\MinGW\bin\sed.exe: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `C'
```

While researching this issue, I came across [this post on the vim_use Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/vim_use/dhJ2HEz0JGU),
which describes the exactly the same problem. It has one reply, suggesting searching for a MinGW curses package.
I found [a repository of MinGW packages](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwrep/files/?source=navbar), but there's no ncurses there. Also, they're really old - the newest was
updated in 2003.

If I change to the `src` directory and run `make` from there, the build process
starts and completes witHout error. It produces a few executables (gvim.exe, vim.exe and a few more)
and dumps them in `src`, but does not create a proper distribution.

The targets for complete distributions are in the root Makefile, such as `dosbin_gvim`,
but I'm getting errors when trying to build this target:

```
$ make dosbin_gvim
rm -rf dist/gvim73.zip
rm -rf dist/vim
mkdir dist/vim
mkdir dist/vim/vim73
tar cf - \
        README_bindos.txt uninstal.txt  \
        | (cd dist/vim/vim73; tar xf -)
find dist/vim/vim73 -type f -exec vim -e -X -u no_title.vim -c ":set tx|wq" {} \;
cp gvim.exe dist/vim/vim73/gvim.exe
cp: cannot stat `gvim.exe': No such file or directory
make: *** [dosbin_gvim] Error 1
```

Using the exe's that are built with the stuff in the `runtime` folder, I could
probably cobble up a distribution myself, but it would be hackish and fragile.
I would much rather know what is causing these errors, and how to fix them.

Answer (score 3):

Building Vim on Windows is very frustrating. **Do not** use `configure`. You should use `Make_ming.mak` directly, for example:

```
make -f Make_ming.mak ARCH=x86-64 OPTIMIZE=MAXSPEED STATIC_STDCPLUS=yes FEATURES=HUGE GUI=yes OLE=yes NETBEANS=no PYTHON="D:/Applications/Python 2.7.3" PYTHON_VER=27 DYNAMIC_PYTHON=yes PYTHON3="D:/Applications/Python 3.2.3" PYTHON3_VER=32 DYNAMIC_PYTHON3=yes gvim.exe
```

Most likely, you'll have to patch `Make_ming.mak` as it contains lots of subtle bugs. For instance, specifying `"D:/Applications/Python 3.2.3"` (as shown above) will not work without patching since `Make_ming.mak` expect you to specify paths without spaces. There are other annoying issues as well, but I don't want to go into details about them here.

If you are looking for fresh 64-bit builds of Vim for Windows, then I'd suggest you try my **[Vim for Windows](https://bitbucket.org/Haroogan/vim-for-windows)** compiled directly from Bram's source code, it includes support for both  Python 2 and Python 3.

**NOTE:** I've built it using **[MinGW-w64](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/)**.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I just compiled VIM on MinGW and made a **[gist about it](https://gist.github.com/rpuntaie/8510218)**. For configure to run through you will need

```
    mingw-get install mingw32-libpdcurses
```

and then you can do

```
    ./configure --with-tlib=pdcurses
```

but to no avail, because `make` will not do its job.

The **[gist](https://gist.github.com/rpuntaie/8510218)** will lead you to a gvim74.exe, which you can use to install just like with the downloaded one.

Comment: I managed to build the exes in the end, using Haroogan's tip and after solving `pdcurses` in a similar manner you suggest, but still had issues with Python. So I threw in the towel and went with distributions such as Haroogan's and [Kaoriya's](http://files.kaoriya.net/vim/vim73-kaoriya-win64-20130706.zip), which work very well. Might give it another shot using your gist when I have the time.